# Double Column lookup for Outline Format Data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

So I am wondering how to find a specific cell in a given Column (in this case column F), when I want the search area for the lookup to be within a certain range, and these ranges will be separated when a new value shows up in column A (because the format for this data is in outline format). I know the description sounds confusing, the picture provide a better explanation than I can. The file format is excel, but I can convert to sheets if necessary.

[image: Outline Format]

So ideally what I want is either a query for some other lookup function that will search the sheet for column A first, so in this case I would search for title contains "ADC-BOH" and then do a sub-search within the area between the two rows with the long column A values (Totals for Dept...) for the Reg Hours. Then repeating that for OT, ESICK, etc.

I don't know how to concatenate a column A value (ADC-BOH) to the Column C value (Reg) to then get the value at column E, and make this dynamic for all of the respective restaurants (Column A) I have to do that are all on this sheet.

Comment: You can do it with Google Apps Script https://developers.google.com/apps-script

Comment: How do you determine when a new value appears in column A?

Comment: Is ADC - BOH(101) the sheet name and is the Sheet in the same spreadsheet?

Comment: Is the cell in the sheet always going to be E3? If so, then try: `var sheetname='string in column A'.slice('string in column A'.indexOf(':')+2); var value=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetname).getRange("E3").getValue();`

Comment: The only value that will appear in A will be the Restaurant name depending on how many subvalues (REG, OT, etc.) fall within that restaurant. "ADC-BOH" is one of the restaurants, there are about 40 in this sheet. The sheet can be named whatever. The location of the cells I need are variable depending on the restaurant. What i would like is some way of defining the search area of the vlookup dynamically so that it looked between two "restaurant" cells to import a value from that area for a cell for that respective restaurant on another sheet (a payroll one).

Comment: My current battleplan is to get a script together which will add a column to the left of A, then in there label every blank cell going down rows as the restaurant above it until it hits a row with a new restaurant in column B (then repeat for that restaurant). This will allow me to Concatenate the restaurant with the subcategory I want to look up so for example: Totals for Department: ADC - BOH(101)Reg. Giving me a unique string I can now vlookup. I don't know if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this.